# Which option best defines cause and effect?

Tags: definition

Which one is a correct definition for cause and effect and fills the gap correctly?

______ tell the reader there might be cause and effect occurring.

A. Signal words/connectors...

OR

B. Events or actions...

Comment: Aaaand welcome to English Language Learners stack exchange! A few tips: 1) This is pretty much the same question you posted earlier in English Language and Usage. You mentioned that you did look up these terms, but it would be helpful if you also mentioned what you found (or didn't find) when you looked them up. Some Stack Exchanges absolutely refuse to just "do your homework for you"; both of these English ones don't have a hard-and-fast rule, but really appreciate when you make it clear that you've put in some effort. Besides that, you get more useful answers when you rule out...

Comment: ...when you rule out what hasn't worked so far. 2) Some of your comments back there were kinda a bit hostile. Take it easy; everybody's here to help. But any time you come into a new web community it takes a second to see how they operate. 3) I just typed "signal word" into Google and it autocompleted "for cause and effect." 4) This is a terrible question for a test or quiz. Both answers can be true. I'm guessing some material that came earlier contained the answer that they want? But it really is true—there are words that can indicate cause and effect, and there are events/actions that can.

Comment: @AndyBonner First : it's not a homework , it was a simple but confusing question that i thought natives would answer it easily . – second : i think everybody here are so worried about correcting questions rather than actually helping and answering it (stackoverflow is different) . – 
third : i thought exchange works pretty the same way that stackoverflow does . but... thank you for (4) . i will send it to my professor to see what he has to say about his bizarre test .

Comment: And lol, I'm not sure I'd tell him to his face that it's a lousy question. One second, let me give a full answer that explains more...

Answer (score 1):

The way it's written, it seems pretty clear that the question expects the first answer. There are [certain words or phrases](https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/570/pulp/hemp5) that often "signal" that we're dealing with cause and effect, like *because*, *so*, and *therefore*.

However, it's also true that events and actions, in context, can indicate cause and effect.

> I spilled a glass of water. The puddle on the floor was huge. I mopped it up.

Although I never used any "signal words," it's clear that the puddle was caused by my spill, and I chose to mop because there was a huge puddle.

Comment: Thank You , I will show him this one XD